# Django - latest object for each object in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

```
class Order(models.Model):
   # ..fields
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to fetch all users, and for each user to add its latest order - e.g the `Order` of the user where date_added is maximum. I want to do this in a **single query** (As in SQL this would be done with one query).

This is what I've tried:

```
users = User.objects.all().annotate(last_order=Max('order__date_added'))
```

But this only gives me the date of the last order, and I want the Order object itself.

Comment: `User.objects.annotate(last_order=Max('order__date_added')).values('order__user', 'last_order').order_by('order__user')` you need to add order by to group by user

Comment: Do I have to use .values()? I still need a queryset instance

Comment: if you don't need to filter by annotate the simple solution is add property(method) to your model user.

Comment: That will require more than one query, I don't think it is possible to filter by a class property

Answer (score 0):

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_latest_order(self):
        return self.order_set.latest('date_added')
```

Views

```
user = User.objects.all()
for u in user:
    print(u.get_latest_order())
```

Comment: This will do a query for each user, that's exactly what I have now and I want to avoid.

Comment: In your question you said "I want to fetch all users, and for each user to add its latest order", so my code fetches all users and their latest order.

Comment: I thought it would be clear that I want to do this in one query. Anyway updated the question

Comment: I still see the same question. Be clear what you want, just user objects, just latest order objects or both.